# Acumatica and Outlook Add-in - Customizations

Tags: acumatica

We are testing the outlook add-in for Acumatica. It seems very promising, and we have read the documentation from Acumatica about how to set it up and use it. However, we have several custom fields that exist on our contact and opportunity forms, and I'm wondering if it's possible to have those brought into the add-in panel so that the user can populate all that is needed within Outlook.

And then similarly, we don't encourage our users to interact with Business Accounts directly, but rather Customer Records/Screens. Is there a way to customize the buttons that show up (hide/remove some and add others)?

Any help or guidance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `Outlook Add-In Read Mode` OU201000 page the target files are:

Graph: PX.Objects.CR.OUSearchMaint

Page: Pages\CR\OU201000.aspx

You can create a graph extension to customize it as usual.

The page can't be customized in the `SCREEN` section of the customization project editor. However you can manually change the ASPX file on disk and do ISS Reset/Restart Application from Apply Updates page to customize it.

After changing the file you should be able to package it in the `FILES` section of the customization if you remove the line `Pages\CR\OU201000.aspx` from the `files.list` ignore file at the root of the website.

Such change is possible but would not pass certification (in case this is a requirement).

Comment: Thank you very much for this direction. it was exactly what we needed to get the customizations done. However, as we started to have our users login, we see an issue that i was wondering if you are aware of how to resolve...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61398664/acumatica-and-outlook-plugin-and

Comment: In more recent version there appears to be limited customizability in the SCREEN section of the customization project editor.